# Foolproof way to hide your IP when browsing

Tags: web-browser, privacy, vpn

is there a fool proof-ish way to hide your IP from websites you visit?

I heard even if you use VPN, there can be 'leaks'?

And one step more secure is Anonymizer or Tor? Can they have 'leaks', too?

I'm using Mac and iPad.

Comment: If anyone gives or sells you something that they say is foolproof, run away.

Answer (score 4):

"Foolproof" does not necessarily means "NSA-proof" or whatever. A foolproof security system is meant to be a system usable by non-technical users and lowering as much as possible the risk of a misconfiguration impacting the security. Browser's, for instance, involve a lot of "foolproof" security technology against phishing sites, etc..

In case of communication tunneling and anonymity, a reference on the domain is [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/), a linux distribution preconfigured in a way that all outgoing traffic should go either through Tor network, or be blocked (cf. the DNS leaks mentioned by @schroeder and how [Tails address them](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Tor_enforcement/DNS/)). Tails can be used as a physical media to boot your PC ([more secure](https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/index.fr.html#index1h1)), or in a virtual machine (more practical).

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a foolproof tool. A VPN can have "leaks" if compromised, which is fairly easy for an experienced person. And Anonymizer and TOR can "leak," because your IP is visible when you connect through the first layer of VPN. That's what TOR is, chained together VPNs. It is, however a lot more secure, because you have other addresses using it at every layer, and at the same time, obscuring your address.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: VPN 'leaks' can happen without compromise. It depends on how it is configured including DNS 'leaks'.

Comment: Didn't think about that one. Thanks for the reminder!!